# heroku stand alone

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy

I have written some code to scrape websites using a python crawling library *scrapy* 
I want to move this code, and this code alone to a heroku server and be able to run it from the heroku dyno.
How do I go about doing that?

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779184/how-to-deploy-scrapy-application-on-heroku-cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python