# How to deploy a Scrapy spider on Heroku cloud

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, scrapy

I developed few spiders in scrapy & I want to test those on Heroku cloud. Does anybody have any idea about how to deploy a Scrapy spider on Heroku cloud?

Comment: scrapy-heroku was written specifically for this purpose: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-heroku

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly simple to deploy and run your Scrapy spider on Heroku.

Here are the steps using a real Scrapy project as example:

1. Clone the project (note that it must have a `requirements.txt` file for Heroku to recognize it as a Python project):

   `git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/testspiders.git`
2. Add cffi to the requirement.txt file (e.g. cffi==1.1.0).
3. Create the Heroku application (this will add a new heroku git remote):

   `heroku create`
4. Deploy the project (this will take a while the first time, when the slug is built):

   `git push heroku main`
5. Run your spider:

   `heroku run scrapy crawl followall`

Some notes:

- Heroku disk is ephemeral. If you want to store the scraped data in a persistent place, you can use a [S3 feed export](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-storage-s3)  (by appending `-o s3://mybucket/items.jl`) or use an addon (like MongoHQ or Redis To Go) and write a pipeline to store your items there
- It would be cool to run a Scrapyd server on Heroku, but it's not currently possible because the `sqlite3` module (which Scrapyd requires) doesn't work on Heroku
- If you want a more sophisticated solution for deploying your Scrapy spiders, consider setting up your own [Scrapyd server](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or using a hosted service like [Scrapy Cloud](https://www.zyte.com/scrapy-cloud/)

Comment: I believe 'heroku run' starts up a One-Off Dyno which will result in costing more money. Is this the only option?

Comment: @Helge one off dynos don't cost any more per minute than standard dynos.

Comment: You can use scrapy-heroku to run a Scrapyd server on heroku!  Has been working great for me. https://github.com/dmclain/scrapy-heroku

Comment: command to run your spider should be: `heroku run scrapy crawl <your_spider_name> --app <your_heroku_app_name>`