# Is it possible to run scrapy on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, screen-scraping, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy to get some data off a website, but I don't want to use my laptop to do it.

Would it be possible to run it as a heroku app? What other options do I have for running a scrapy spider on a remote server?

Thankss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use [Scrapy on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779184/how-to-deploy-a-scrapy-spider-on-heroku-cloud). Other options include setting up [Scrapyd](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html) on a remote server, or using [Scrapy Cloud](http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [scrapy-heroku](https://github.com/dmclain/scrapy-heroku) to run a Scrapyd server on heroku!  No problem.