# Does google app engine support out-standard python lib?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, saas, paas

I want a python program with `scrapy` lib, for crawling website, and I want deploy it to the google app.

But I heard the google app only support the standard python lib, so my program can't deploy to it? Does any hack I can do?

If the google app real doesn't support, is there any other Saas or Paas platform could support    out-standard python lib?

How about `appfog`, `Heroku`(does it still free now) ?

Comment: You can include additional libraries, *provided* they do not use C extensions, and do not expect to run in some sort of daemon / threaded fashion (like Scrapy does).

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine supports more than the just standard python library, and you can upload any pure python library.

However, you can not run scrapy on AppEngine due to how it relies on threads.

I have no idea about appfog, but Heroku is more than capable for running scrapy.

See: [How to deploy a Scrapy spider on Heroku cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779184/how-to-deploy-a-scrapy-spider-on-heroku-cloud)